# How do I create element locator dynamically?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new in the Watir world. I thought my problem was easy but I am not able to get it done.

Here is my code:

```
 names = Hash.new
 names[:text] = 'Image'
 puts names
 browser.a("#{names}").click
```

I am getting this error:

```
'extract_selector': expected Hash or (:how, 'what'), got ["{:text=>\"Image\"}"]   (ArgumentError)
```

`print` is showing the correct value as `"{:text=>"Image"}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully - *'extract_selector': expected Hash or (:how, 'what')*

Try this :

```
browser.a(:text => 'Image').click
           :how     :what
```

Then do (as per OP's comment)

```
browser.a(names).click
           Hash
```

Here is the full code :

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)"
# <a href="/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation" title="Just-in-time compilation">just-in-time compilation</a>
hsh = {:text => 'just-in-time compilation'}
b.a(hsh).text # => "just-in-time compilation"
```

Comment: My problem is I want to create :text => 'Image' dynamically. I will be getting property name(text) and value(Image) in run time and then I want to find element using that.

Comment: @Pratik so.. key and value both are dynamic?

Comment: Yes. both are dynamic

Comment: Thank you Arup. I guess it is going to take time for me to understand Ruby. After seeing your answer I modified my code to

    browser.a(names).click

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It says it expected a Hash, so don't give it a String:

```
browser.a(names).click
```

?